# What does "She was sick of old men leering at her." mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the following sentence mean?

> She was sick of old men leering at her.

Comment: The implication is that they are "checking her out" (sexually).

Comment: And she does not like it, and is tired of it

Answer (score 2):

If you say somebody is sick of something, you mean that they're tired or fed up with whatever that thing is. For example, a student who has a lot of homework to do might say "I'm sick of doing homework."

> leer (verb):
>
> 1. to look with a sideways or oblique glance, especially suggestive of lascivious interest or sly and malicious intention
>
> [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/leer)

We're particularly interested in the "lascivious interest" part, so:

> lascivious (adjective):
>
> 3. indicating sexual interest or expressive of lust or lewdness
>
> [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lascivious)

So she is tired of old men looking at her in a way that expresses sexual interest.

Answer (score 0):

> She was [sick of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sick+of) old men [leering](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leering) at her.

She was tired of old men always looking at her with sexual desire.

Answer (score 0):

*The old men were leering at her*, i.e. they were giving her lecherous looks.

*She was fed up of that happening*.

This implies that either it had been going on for a long time  (those old men had  stamina for their leering), or that it had been happening a lot (those old men were just the latest old men in a long series of leerers).

*To be sick of something* is a metaphor - she hated it so much that it was making her nauseous, figuratively speaking.